# Which connector do we need to use the put the file in share path location in mule cloud

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

I want to put the csv file in shared path location. I tired with file connector. It does not work.Which connector do we need to use the put the file in share path location in mule cloud.

Answer (score 0):

In mule CloudHub, as far I know, you cannot access File system for security reasons.
You can only access a location called `/tmp` in cloud.
If you look at documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/deployment-strategies#disk-persistence , its mentioned:

**"** CloudHub does not guarantee that writing to disk survives hardware failures. Instead, you must use an external storage mechanism to store information. For small amounts of data, you can use the Object Store. For applications that have large data storage requirements, we recommend use of a cloud service such as Amazon S3. For temporary storage, **the File connector is still available and can be used with the /tmp directory.** **"**

You need to contact your mule support if you want to access cloudhub File system for your File connector

Comment: can you put the file in sharepath using powershell connector

Answer (score 0):

Regarding which connector to use, Better to use FTP/SFTP , AWS storage or any cloud rather than local file system.

About local file system, below are the details about tmp space available in cloudhub absed on vcores
Tmp space only available with With 2 vCores and more 
With 2 vCores Memory available is 3.5 GB Storage 8GB and 32 GB in /tmp
With 4 vCores Memory vailable is 7.5 GB Storage  8 GB and 40 GB in /tmp and 40 GB in /opt/storage.

With Cloudhub, workers are created fresh when a the application is deployed (or redeployed) and destroyed when an application stops (as done during redeploy).

Another option is to use on-prem file system as Cloud-hub environment can be integrated with on-prem servers using VPC
Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/virtual-private-cloud

Comment: Could you relate you answer to the question in more obvious way?

Comment: OkThanks. Edited my original post